# how to call a generic parameterized method bounded JAVA?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to know how I can call a bounded parameterized method.

For example, I have the following method :

```
  public static<R extends Reader & Runnable> R foo(R r) {
         r.run();
         return r;
  }
```

I would like to know how to call this method.

I try the following code :

```
    private static class Test extends Reader implements Runnable {
        ...........
    }

    private static <T extends extends & Runnable> T getInstance() {
        return (T) new Test(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(getInstance());
    }
```

But I have the following exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class ent.Main$Test cannot be cast to class java.lang.Runnable (ent.Main$Test is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Runnable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

And I can not find the solution.

Can someone have an idea?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Worked for me (Java 10). Are you sure you pasted the code correctly? And what if you call `foo(new Test())`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  You have some typos.  Can you please put in all the classes, even if they are just skeletons?  And show  what classes contain other methods and classes.  But when I guessed and modified it myself, it appeared to work.

Comment: I guess you mean `T extends Reader & Runnable`, rather than `T extends extends & Runnable`?

Comment: @Zefick You're right. It was me who was wrong. In fact, I used the wrong class. I found it odd that it did not work.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
private static <T extends Reader & Runnable> T getInstance() {
```

means that the method can return something that can be cast to *any* class which both extends `Reader` and implements `Runnable`. However, there is only one such value that you can return safely from this:

```
return null;
```

Anything else could result in a `ClassCastException`. In particular, `return new Test();` will only succeed if you happen to have invoked is in a context expecting to receive a `Test`.

In general, you can't safely return a non-null `T` from a method if `T` does not feature in the formal parameters. See the documentation of [Error Prone's `TypeParameterUnusedInFormals` check](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/TypeParameterUnusedInFormals) for more detail.

If you want to return an instance of `Test` from `getInstance()`, drop the generics and make the return type `Test`.

```
private static Test getInstance() {
    return new Test(); 
}
```

Comment: Whenever a poor Generic is drowning in the seas, Andy comes to the rescue!

Comment: Hello @Andy Turner, thank you for this response. When you mention " In general, you can't safely return a non-null T from a method if T does not feature in the formal parameters.  " I have an example
 ```Foo foo = new Foo();
        FunctionCatalog functionCatalog = new FunctionCatalog() {
            @Override
            public <T> T lookup(Class<?> type, String functionDefinition, String... expectedOutputMimeTypes) {
                return (T) type.cast(foo);
            }```
And I am not understanding the error prone flag

Comment: @PatPanda if `foo` is an instance of `Foo`, `type.cast(foo)` will only succeed if `type` is `Foo.class` or the class object for a superclass, or the class object for some interface implemented by `Foo`. If you passed in, say, `String.class`, it would fail at runtime. But the compiler isn't able to stop you passing in the wrong `type`.

Comment: Btw, the fact that you pass in a `Class<?>` means that you don't get compile time checking at the call site: you could do something like `Foo f = functionCatalog.lookup(String.class, ...);`, which is obviously nonsense. Change the type of `type` to `Class<? extends T>` to make it a little bit safer, because at least you are saying it ought to be something castable to a `T` then (and also the explicit `(T)` becomes unnecessary).